# I got banned for one dumb question?

Tags: discussion

I have that message when I try to ask question on superuser:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the
>   Help Center to learn more.

[My reputation history](https://superuser.com/users/121072/kamil?tab=reputation) is not bad, it's almost empty, even when "show removed posts" is checked.

Is this some kind of bug or deleting one dumb question about fedora download caused my ban?

This is my reputation history (I think screenshot is better than copy-paste):

[image]

I have accounts on Stackoverflow (5k reputation), Electrical Engineering (2k reputation) and... ban here.

Comment: If you click my reputation history or activity - you will see that I have nothing really bad there...

Comment: I have no questions... Nothing to fix.

Comment: What about "Where to download Fedora 10?"? I had +50 rep from that...

Comment: An answer with several postive votes does not help when your questions are not well recieved.  As I originally indicate most of your questions were not well recieved and then deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/201411). Read everything in the original question and the accepted answer. There's really nothing more we can tell you.

And as the answer says, moderators **cannot** lift the ban. Only you can lift your ban by contributing to the site.

Comment: I know that moderators cannot lift ban. Just wanted to report weird service behavior. I started with just bad question and ban... I think that was too quick.

Comment: I looked at the image you posted, and it was far from just one question. You've had 5 downvotes, 2 questions removed, and at least a net -8 on one of your questions (or answers; I can't tell from the screenshot). Your claim that it was just one question / event is patently false. This is not a bug at all; the auto-ban functionality is operating correctly. Both downvotes and deleted posts count against your auto-ban. Even though you have considerable rep, having something like 50% of the total votes logged against your posts as downvotes is not going to cut it.

Comment: Even on the days where you had net positive reputation, where you didn't expand the arrow to show the up/down log, it appears you received several downvotes. It's not possible to get net rep of 2, 3, 7, 8, etc. without receiving at least a few downvotes (or downvoting others). Downvoting others doesn't count against you, but I'd have to assume at least some of that lost rep is due to you *being* downvoted, which *does* count against you.

Comment: OK. I found it. My question was not dumb, it had +2 votes, I deleted it, -50 rep for that. Then I got banned for asking about mac osx test version here:  http://superuser.com/questions/396283/virtual-machine-and-mac-osx And this is how to kick out someone from community :( I will try to repair my account by some answers.

Comment: Oh, it had +2 votes one day, +3 other. +5 total, thats 50 reputation.

Comment: With that many upvotes, it probably would've done you more good to keep it there than to delete it.

Comment: @Kamil you're not banned from answering, you're banned from asking. Your only post with any significant upvotes was an answer with +5. Meanwhile, you have 5 questions, all deleted, with scores of 0, -4, 0, 1, and -5. You yourself deleted most of those, so if you were to undelete them and edit them to be better questions, there's a chance the question ban would be lifted due to improvements, but there's no way for us to know for sure.

Answer (score 7):

You got banned because you asked questions which were not well received. Out of your 5 questions asked:

- 2 were closed
- 2 received negative scores
- 5 were deleted

Deleting a question that wasn't well received isn't helping you. You should improve those questions or, even better, not ask questions like that in the first place.