# I have reached my question limit?

Tags: discussion

Can someone explain why I can't ask more questions?

When I try to ask - I have notification like this:

"You have reached your question limit"

How can I fix it? I have tried to delete my 0-rating questions, but I still can't create new question.

**Edit:**

I have 4 questions. Two have negative (-1) feedback:

[Differences between Intel i7 "M" and "U" series](https://superuser.com/questions/814541/differences-between-intel-i7-m-and-u-series)

one guy downvoted and nobody else looking at it after I fixed my question by removing sentence about shopping.

Another example:

[How can I stream a game running on one computer to play on another?](https://superuser.com/questions/811128/remote-desktop-software-for-gaming-still-nothing-in-2014)

So, my average is below zero now, because I didn't asked about anything popular yet. This is not fair.

Comment: Deleting zero upvoted questions *probably* makes it worse.

Comment: The answers you received [here](http://meta.superuser.com/q/8375/76571) are still relevant.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new mechanism to augment the low quality question ban system.

Instead of outright banning users it will rate limit them. I believe the limit may be variable but I have seen a potential of 1 question per week.

The upshot should be that it is harder to get banned by asking questions that are poorly received, the downside is that you are instead rate limited until you gain enough high quality posts.

This link [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271543/278545) suggests that the system was only live to SO, but is is possible it has been enabled network wide.

> **How is the length of time that I'm limited actually calculated?**
>
> It's based on your average question score, how long you tend to wait between asking questions, how well you participate in other ways on the site, and how often you tend to revisit and improve your posts, even the positively scored ones. We don't provide the actual formula and details, but only because we want folks to focus on what the system is trying to tell them, rather than trying to find ways around it.
>
> Rate limits vary from 1 to 7 days.

Reading further into that post suggests there are many parts that go into calculating the rate limit and I suspect that 0-rated questions pose much less of a factor in the calculation than, say, deleted questions...

---

Before you read this, notice it's length.  I *am* trying to be helpful and provide some constructive advice here.  Knowledge is a two way street.

Regarding the [CPU question](https://superuser.com/questions/814541/differences-between-intel-i7-m-and-u-series) you tell us you know "about: core voltage, TDP, socket, price"  But don't provide any useful information to us about *what* you know so that we can rule them out of looking into the matter, you also do not narrow the question down to a specific processor that has a 'U' and 'M' variant for people to look at more closely and tell you if you are missing anything.

We value signs of research but you haven't provided any.

As to the [other question](https://superuser.com/questions/811128/remote-desktop-software-for-gaming-still-nothing-in-2014) you linked we expect a question to say more than "I found this old question, is there anything new?"  In this case I would much rather the question have been along the lines of you having tried out various RDP softwares and found them wanting, and asking whether there are any technical limitations on how quickly a screen can be passed over the network.  You *could* have asked why technologies like [Nvidia Gamestream](http://shield.nvidia.com/play-pc-games/) can do it so much better.

Quite simply there was no real *meat* in the question.  It came off as if you couldn't be bothered to look yourself and just decided to ask us instead.

Again, we value signs of research but you didn't provide any.

As to your most recently asked (and deleted) question, you think your question is simple, but it isn't.

You could have done with telling us *what* the technology you were asking about was rather than assuming everyone knows what an obscure term (CUVID) means, what it does, *why* you needed it or what kind of problems you were having because of it.  Just asking "does this do that" doesn't really get anyone invested in the answer.  At best they'll type "Quadro NVS 140M CUVID" into Google, find nothing (like I did) and then move on.

You need to tell people that you've already done that and provide whatever else made you ask the question.

I had to actually go out and figure out what CUVID was in the first place:

- CUVID is a Cuda accelerated video decoder, [apparently](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4380/discrete-htpc-gpus-shootout/13), though information about it is hard to find outside of dedicated video encoding forums
- This means that you *might* be having a problem with hardware video decoding (or encoding, I don't know).  But apparently CUVID has a counterpart in [DirectX Video Acceleration](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?p=1569761#post1569761) so I don't know what's wrong with just using that.
- CUVID is insanely specific and seems to have been deprecated in favour of something else, I can't explain why else there is so little information on it.  Everything I can find is from 2009 to 2012
- I can't search any further because I don't know *why* you need this or what is causing a problem without it.

You almost certainly would have already known all these little bits, otherwise you would not have asked *that* specific a question.

By assuming that your question is "Easy, anyone would know this" you are raising an immediate barrier to entry in answering it.

If you'd have been upfront with some research, or even edited your question to include some, then we could have prodded back with questions on what it is (or isn't) doing, maybe gotten invested in it.

As it is the question festered and you eventually deleted it.

We are a site for problems and solutions.  You need to tell us the story of your problem so that we can go round looking for solutions.

If you post a question that looks like Google-fodder, but on closer inspection is a rather strange nightmare, then people are going to pass you over and look for the next easy question.

From the page [How to ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) the first line makes it clear: **We’d love to help you**

I would dearly love to help you find out what is going wrong with your graphics card.  Now that I've written this and done some research I'm invested, I'm curious.  It's up to you though to [edit your question](https://superuser.com/questions/816296/nvidia-cuvid-in-quadro-nvs140m) to let me (and others) help.

Comment: See my edit please and tell me thats normal. If it is - I probably should delete my account on this overreacting site.

Comment: @Kamil My reply was too long for a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will fix my CUVID question, but... I don't believe anyone notice that and it will be there with 0 answers forever. That's why I was deleting my other unanswered questions - to clean up my mess on this site.

Comment: If you delete a question how can somebody answer it?